# Call R functions in RcppArmadillo with armadillo data type

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am translating my R code with some prepared functions to RcppArmadillo. I want to use some of these functions directly in my Rcpp code,instead of translating. For example, I want to call the `sigma2` function:

```
sigma2<- function(xi.vec,w.vec,log10lambda,n,q){
  lambda <- 10^log10lambda
  (1/(n-q))*sum((lambda*xi.vec*(w.vec^2))/(lambda*xi.vec+1))
}
```

A typical Rcpp code is as below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP myS(){

  Rcpp::Environment myEnv = Rcpp::Environment::global_env();
  Rcpp::Function myS = myEnv["sigma2"];
  arma::vec xvec = myEnv["xi.vec"];
  arma::vec wvec = myEnv["w.vec"];
  double l = myEnv["log10lambda"];
  int n = myEnv["n"];
  int q = myEnv["q"];

  return myS(Rcpp::Named("xi.vec",xvec),
             Rcpp::Named("w.vec",wvec),
             Rcpp::Named("l",l),
             Rcpp::Named("n",n),
             Rcpp::Named("q",q));
}
```

Of course it works. But my problem is that in my case, the parameters of `sigma2` function should be defined before as output of another function(say `func1`) in RcppArmadillo and they have armadillo data type. For instance, `xi.vec` and `w.vec` have `vec` type. Now I want to know how can I modified this code to call `sigma2`? Do I need to change my environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just say *no* to embedding R functions and environments into C++ routines. There is *no* speedup in this case; only a considerable *slowdown*. Furthermore, there is a greater potential for things to go cockeye if the variables are not able to be retrieved in the `global.env` scope.

---

In your case, you seem to be calling `myS()` from within `myS()` with no terminating condition. Thus, your function will never *end*.

e.g.

```
SEXP myS(){

Rcpp::Function myS = myEnv["sigma2"];

return myS(Rcpp::Named("xi.vec",xvec),
           Rcpp::Named("w.vec",wvec),
           Rcpp::Named("l",l),
           Rcpp::Named("n",n),
           Rcpp::Named("q",q));
}
```

Switch one to be `myS_R` and `myS_cpp`.

---

Regarding environment hijacking, you would need to pass down to C++ the values. You cannot reach into an R function to obtain values specific passed to it before it is called.

e.g.

```
SEXP myS_cpp(arma::vec xvec, arma::vec wvec, double l, int n, int q){
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Not a "considerable" slowdown; it adds a layer so it measurable but you make it sound too dramatic.